# Horizontal Scroller in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How to make Horizontal Scroll allow in UITableView ? I add label in cell content view with frame. However, can't show in Portrait view. I want to allow horizontal scroll bar on Portrait view. I already check on Scrollers Horizontal in UITableView but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't have a horizontal scroll in uitableview.

Maybe you should associate with UIScrollView to be able having a horizontal scroll ^^

You see the trick ?

Good Luck !

Comment: UITableView can't put under UIScrollView because UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView